# Tab to Search in Chrome With AJAX Post Search Engine

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opensearch

My site has a search function that uses AJAX to complete the search.  A POST request is sent to a PHP page and a results DIV is reloaded using the HTML returned.

I'd like to implement Chrome's tab to search feature using OpenSearch XML.  I've been following the answer given at
[How to add google chrome omnibox-search support for your site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site).  The answer shows an example of how to implement the tab to search function using a GET request where the search is executed on a separate page.

How would I implement the tab to search function on a search engine that uses AJAX POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up pushing a GET request to my index(search) page.

```
$search = $_GET["search"];
```

If a GET variable is supplied then the POST search is automatically performed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $search = "<?php echo $search; ?>";
    if(search != "" && search != null){
        $.post("search.php", {search: search},
            function(data){
            $("#returneddiv").html(data);
        });
    }
});
```