# Show search feature of our website in address bar while entering name of site

Tags: html, search, address-bar

If on address bar, you type stackoverflow.com the browser (atleast google chrome does) displays the following message

Press *Tab* to search Stack Overflow

How can I manage to do that in my site? Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add google chrome omnibox-search support for your site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site)

Answer (score 0):

use "tabindex" for the input fields. you can set the tab order too

For example:

```
<input name="name1" type="text"  tabindex="1"  />
<input name="name2" type="text"  tabindex="3"  />
<input name="name3" type="text"  tabindex="2"  />
```

so if you press tab button, the order will be like --> name1-->name3-->name2