# Hoogle as a Chrome search engine

Tags: google-chrome, haskell, hoogle

Do someone knows how to set Hoogle as a Google Chrome search engine?

Hackage is already there on those steps:

1. Click on Chrome search bar
2. Type "Hackage"
3. Press Tab key
4. Write whatever you want to search for

Comment: @closevoters Hoogle is an API search engine for the Haskell programming language, which lets you search for functions by type not just by name, and can find functions with logically related (as opposed to just textually related) types. It is most certainly a tool for programming, _not_ a general search engine.

Comment: @AndrewC True, but this is a question about how to use chrome, not about how to use hoogle.

Comment: It's a question about how to integrate hoogle into chrome. This question was closed thoughtlessly. A text editor can be used to write all manner of things, and a question about using word-wrap would be off-topic, but a question about hoogle integration would be on-topic. Same goes for a browser. Hoogle integration for chrome is a tool used only by programmers, and only for programming. Saying it isn't about using hoogle is simply incorrect. There's no close reason for "I can do this easily" for a very deliberate reason; the site is about learning, not about newbie bashing.

Comment: Mr. @closevoters and AndrewC, I know very well what Hoogle is... If Hoogle site (not API) had this LINK HTML flag it would be automatically recognizable by Chrome browser as a search engine. I search in Hoogle often via Chrome browser that is why I'm asking this question. And Mr. GarethR gave very good answer. I'm thankful!
I had already written feature request to Hoogle's developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Hoogle manual:

**Chrome Integration**
As a keyword search: With a keyword search you can type h map directly into the location bar to perform a Hoogle search. Go to the Hoogle website in Chrome, right-click in the Hoogle search field and select "Add as a search engine...". Give it a keyword such as "h".

https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The real answer of this question is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site

This is what other search engines add to their HTML code to be automatically recognized by Chrome...
But @GarethR gave me good idea how to overcome this missing feature in Hoogle site.