# How to add multiple search engines in chrome settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opensearch, opensearchdescription

I am using Opensearch in my site to be able to [*search directly using Chrome omnibox*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site)

However, I want my site to able to add multiple search engines (different domains) via **OpenSearchDescription** xml.
I tried adding multiple search description xmls and referencing them in my index html, but only the search engine referenced in the last search description xml is added in chrome settings. Is there a way to add multiple search engines??

I even tried writing a chrome extension, but it too was able to add only one search engine.

I also observed that opening site in iframe doesn't help the browser (Chrome in my case) to add the entry in search engines.

Any help with adding multiple search engines via opensearch or via chrome extension is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible in the local browser:  Select text on a web page -> Right click. But this is possible using chrome extension as stated in this [issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43680) (this is quiet old). This [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga), can be used to search for selected text using the context menu. Different search engines can be added according to the user's wish to the right-click menu. Hope this helps.