# How to make a website searchable by chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search

Didn't know how to phrase my question but I'll try to explain it here.

Have you seen how you can start typing a website URL in chrome's then hit [TAB] and then chrome's URL bar will jump into a searchy status?

For example, type 'facebook.com' in your address bar, then hit [TAB]. what you type in now will be searched for inside facebook.

What does facebook have to have for it to work?

Comment: `For example, type 'facebook.com' in your address bar, then hit [TAB]. what you type in now will be searched for inside facebook.` -- That's not what happened to me when I tried it.  It cycled through my most recently-used URLs from Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the thing youre talking about is called omnibox, and here's a link to a similar question which includes loads of detailed answers: [How to add google chrome omnibox-search support for your site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site)

Hope this helps.

Edit: For those reading wondering why they can't replicate the facebook example given in the question, omnibox doesnt always work for everyone, its always been iffy on my work computer but works perfectly at home, I believe its something to do with the browser settings (official advice is just to reset them and try again!)

Comment: I think the omnibox is literally the address bar in chrome. Thanks for directing me to the other post!