# When I type at google "youtube.com <space> serach" it directly search the result at youtube and open the searched page.how to make it?

Tags: javascript, youtube

[image]

While typing "youtube.com" I typed one `<space>` by mistake and it gives "search on youtube" where we can directly search on youtube without actually going in to the search bar of the youtube.

Can we implement the same thing for our own website?

Is it possible for beginners?

If you know how to do it then please tell...

Comment: This is a similar question: [How to add google chrome omnibox-search support for your site?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7630144) But you have to click tab in order to activate it