# Website's internal search URL to use in browser's address bar

Tags: html, web, browser, progressive-web-apps, meta-tags

There are so many websites what when you enter it's url in address bar and hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, browser gets ready to send your query to that specific website. It seems that websites can manage that internal URL.

The question is: **How I can specify that internal search URL?**

some examples below:

#### Google Translate

[image]

After pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

After typing `something` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

As you see, my typed word is in a custom URL (which obviously my Edge doesn't generated it)

#### Nic.ir

Another Iranian website [nic.ir](https://nic.ir) with the same steps.

[image]

[image]

What this technique is called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add google chrome omnibox-search support for your site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site)

Comment: Browsers track where you go. They try to anticipate based on what you are entering in the OmniBox. You cannot feed that, at least not yet.
In your application's search box you could because you know what is available in your site/app.

Comment: Thanks @Omkar76, that's the exact address.